# cURL intermittently failing to resolve domains, while dig always resolves successfully

Tags: domain-name-system

We have two machines that periodically query various external resources using cURL. Beginning a couple of days ago, these requests have begun intermittently failing with `Could not resolve host: www.example.com`.

Or from the command line:
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.example.com`

This is happening for numerous different domains, but apparently not ALL domains. I wrote a script to try to connect to one of these domains every 5 seconds, as well as looking it up using dig and getent. The curl call will generally fail for about a minute every few minutes, while dig and getent consistent resolve successfully. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..500}
do
    printf "\ndig short:\n"
    dig +short www.example.com
    printf "\ngetent:\n"
    getent ahosts www.example.com
    printf "\ncURL v4:\n"
    curl -sSI -4 https://www.example.com

    sleep 5
done
```

And the raw output when curl fails:

```
dig short:
r9fe7.x.incapdns.net.
107.154.108.172

getent:
107.154.108.172 STREAM r9fe7.x.incapdns.net
107.154.108.172 DGRAM
107.154.108.172 RAW

cURL v4:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.example.com
```

I've tried specifying various public nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf, including 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8, to no effect. I've also tried explicitly setting the nameserver for dig and curl, but still dig always succeeds while curl intermittently fails to resolve.

In /etc/nsswitch.conf I have
`hosts:      files dns myhostname`

I'm not sure what else could cause curl to periodically fail to resolve hosts, while `dig` and `getent ahosts www.example.com` work consistently.

Comment: Does `curl -q ...` fail the same way?

Comment: @htor trying that now - seems whatever intermittent issue is causing this isn't present at the moment though, so will have to wait for it to come back to know if there's any difference. There aren't any curlrc files on the machine though, so if I understand -q correctly, it should be the same.

Comment: Would you like to post (a link to) your script too?

Comment: Sure, though there's nothing much to it. Will add to the question.